# Is a malloc() needed before a realloc()?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, alloc

Since I had read realloc will act as malloc if the size pointed is 0, I was using it without malloc(), provided the pointer was static, global, or explicitly set to NULL if automatic.

However, I notice a lot of programmers try to set it or set it to malloc(1). Is it needed?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From [Open Groups' specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html):

> If ptr is a null pointer, realloc()
>   shall be equivalent to malloc() for
>   the specified size.
>
> If ptr does not match a pointer
>   returned earlier by calloc(),
>   malloc(), or realloc() or if the space
>   has previously been deallocated by a
>   call to free() or realloc(), the
>   behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 14):

`malloc` is not required, you can use `realloc` only.

`malloc(n)` is equivalent to `realloc(NULL, n)`.

However, it is often clearer to use `malloc` instead of special semantics of `realloc`. It's not a matter of what works, but not confusing people reading the code.

(Edit: removed mention of `realloc` acting as `free`, since it's not standard C. See comments.)

Comment: Be aware that the C99 standard for realloc with size 0 differs slightly from the POSIX standard.  The C99 standard says just this: *If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value*.

Comment: So can one do "p = malloc(n)" followed by "realloc(p, 0)"  when p is not NULL? I wouldn't really do it! Sorry about the formatting

Comment: Jeremy, isn't that related to 'requested' size? What does it have to do with reallocation of the previous pointer?

Comment: `realloc(p,0)` is unfortunately not equivalent to `free(p)`. Both plain C and POSIX allow implementations which return a new pointer to an area you're not allowed to write to (it has "length 0") in place of `NULL`. Sadly glibc is one such implementation, and there's no shortage of buggy programs which expect the glibc behavior and use these massively-wasteful "size 0" allocations (which take at least 16 bytes each) for their own bookkeeping.

Comment: @R., interesting, you're right. I only checked the Linux manpage for `realloc`, not the C standard. The standard does not imply anything about `realloc` being able to free memory. I'll edit my answer accordingly.